# webserver to be in ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu-10.04

how to set up a webserver in a webbrowser to be used
in ubuntu 10.04 to transfer files from computer to
tfr 2400 receiver

Answer (score 0):

The TRF 2400 has its own ftp and web servers. To enable the web server, you can select Installation -> Network settings -> Web server -> Enable.

Once this has been set up you then enter IP address of the TFR 2400 in your web browser's address bar, and you can transfer your files to and from the receiver.

If you want to access the receiver from outside your LAN, you will need to set up port forwarding rules on your router.

It is explained in the manual. If you do not have a copy, it can be doenloaded from [here](http://www.i-topfield.com/eng/product/detail.asp?idx=242).